# AIX create directory when copying

Tags: directory, cp, aix

What is the best way to create a directory that does not exist when copying files in AIX? Something like this:

```
ssh server1 'cp -R ~user1/bin/log ~user2/bin/log'
cp: /u/user2/bin/log: No such file or directory
ssh server1 'cp -r ~user1/bin/log ~user2/bin/log'
cp: /u/user2/bin/log: No such file or directory
```

The ~user2/ directory exists, but not the ~user2/bin directory.

Comment: and I assume (!?!?) that `log` is a directory, based on your examples of recursively copying it?

Comment: I have updated my answer to accommodate ~user2 not having a ~/bin directory.

Comment: @JeffSchaller No `log` is just one single file I want to copy over. I thought using the recursive option would create the directory for me if they were not there.

Comment: @JeffSchaller it worked :). Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be to use a tar pipeline:

```
(cd ~user1/ && tar -c -p -f - bin/log) | (cd ~user2/ && tar -x -p -f -)
```

This uses a subshell to change to the parent directory of the source location, then tells `tar` to write an archive of the "log" directory to stdout. The second subshell changes to the parent directory of the destination, then tells `tar` to extract the archive that's coming over the pipe's stdin. The `tar` commands are chained with `&&` to execute only if the corresponding `cd` command succeeds.

You can test this by telling the second `tar` to simply print the incoming contents; just change the `-x` to `-t`. Using `-p` with `-t` doesn't matter and doesn't hurt:

```
(cd ~user1/ && tar -c -p -f - bin/log) | (cd ~user2/ && tar -t -p -f -)
```

Comment: Can you think of a way to do this with rsync? This seems like a task that rsync should be designed to do.